# How to increase Azure Service Bus Queue Size?

Tags: azure, service, azureservicebus

I am trying to create a windows azure service bus queue with a maximum size of 20GB.

My understanding is that the maximum allowed size is 80GB, but I am not able to create a queue larger than 5GB if I use the "Custom Create" button or 16GB if I use the "Quick Create" button on Azure's portal.

I've also tried to do this pragmatically as follow:

```
if (!namespaceManager.QueueExists(queueName))
{
    var queueDescription = new QueueDescription(queueName)
    {
        MaxSizeInMegabytes = 20480,
        DefaultMessageTimeToLive = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0, 0)
    };
    namespaceManager.CreateQueue(queueDescription);
}
```

But the following exception was thrown:

```
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. SubCode=40000. 
The specified value 20480 is invalid. 
The property MaxSizeInMegabytes, must be one of the following values: 
1024;2048;3072;4096;5120
```

Any ideas on how to create a service bus queue with a max size of 20GB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty clear from the error message what are the possible options for a Service Bus Queue.

It can also clearly be seen from the official documentation on [Service Bus Quotas and Limits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee732538.aspx). Besides, the size cannot be changed once the queue has been created!

**UPDATE**

After technically proving, creating a **partitioned** queue with Max Size of **5G** gives actually a Queue with max size of 80G. Undocumented and unexpected, but that is the result:

[image]

Comment: Seemingly there's a discrepancy in the documentation. If you look at "Capacity & Quotas" section here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh767287.aspx, it is mentioned that Service Bus Queues can be from 1 - 80 GB in size.

Comment: agree about the discrepancy ... here also the max size is 5GB: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh780773.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: The URL shared by Gaurav states that azure service bus queues maximum queue size between 1 GB to 80 GB if partition is enabled. I have tried that, but the same error message was generated :(

Comment: It might be the case that when when you use partitioning, each partition gets the define maximum size - so 16 Partitions 5GB each = 80GB. But this is just speculation and needs to be confirmed ....

Comment: I believe Premium SKU permits 80GB